# How to require password on delay after screen timeout?

Tags: linux-mint, screensaver, lock-screen

I have my machine set to time out after 5 minutes and shut off the display and require password.

The inconvenience comes from the fact that I often work on another machine and reference the first one, so when the first one times out, I have to stop what I am doing to type a password.

What I would like is an option similar to what a lot of android phones do: turn off the display at the 5 minute timeout, but not actually lock the screen until a few seconds later. That way, if the screen shuts off while I'm using it, I can just move the mouse quickly and it will come right back up. However if I walk away it will actually lock on its own.

Can this be done? I'm using Mint 13

Answer (score 1):

There is a program [`blueproximity`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=702372) (see also [this](http://www.automaticable.com/2008-09-20/lock-down-your-ubuntu-computer-with-a-bluetooth-cellphone-and-blueproximity/))

> BlueProximity is a clever program by Lars Friedrichs that sets up your
>   computer to lock itself when your phone is out of bluetooth range, and
>   unlock itself when it comes close enought again. You can also also
>   make it turn off and on the monitor, music, change msn status and
>   pretty much everything you can imagine.

Maybe not the 100% answer to your question, but it might solve your problem.

Comment: That looks cool.